# discord.js Welcome message

Tags: discord, discord.js

yea hello I'm making a discord.js bot and I have this code currently and it REFUSES to send a message (it doesn't error either

```
  let chx = db.get(`welchannel_${member.guild.id}`);

  if (chx === null) {

    return;

  }

  

   let data = await canva.welcome(member, { link: "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f3/1c/39/f31c39d56512dc8fbf30f9d0fb3ee9d3.jpg" })

 

    const attachment = new discord.MessageAttachment(

      data,

      "welcome-image.png"

    );

  

  

  client.channels.cache.get(chx).send("Welcome to our Server " + member.user.username, attachment);

});
```

and then i have welcome.js with this code but it aint sending and i cant figure out why ...

````
const db = require("quick.db")

module.exports = {
  name: "setwelcome",
  category: "moderation",
  usage: "setwelcome <#channel>",
  description: "Set the welcome channel",
  run: (client, message, args) => {
    
    let channel = message.mentions.channels.first()
    
    if(!channel) {
      return message.channel.send("Please Mention the channel first")
    }
    
    //Now we gonna use quick.db
    
    db.set(`welchannel_${message.guild.id}`, channel.id)
    
    message.channel.send(`Welcome Channel is set to ${channel}`)
  }
}```
````

Comment: What exactly does `chx` return, can you log it and see?

Comment: chx is the channel id of the channel u selected other whys it would be longer and be welchannel_

Comment: However `welchannel_ID` Isn't a valid snowflake. If `chx` isnt a snowflake then `Channels#get` will not return a channel object

Comment: so how would i make this work-

Comment: By having `chx` return an id

Answer (score 0):

just a guess that your not checking for undefined on CHX

```
 if (chx === null && chx === undefined) {

    return;

  }
```

Comment: Any errors? can you try doing a `.catch` on some parts or `console.log` some of your variables?

Answer (score 0):

This is my modified code from my discord bot (just to keep it general).

```
this.client.on('ready', () => {
    if(botChannelID){
        this.client.channels.fetch(botChannelID).then(ch => {
            ch.send(`Welcome message here.`);
        }).catch(e => {
            console.error(`Error: ${e}`);
        });
    }
    //Other stuff. Blah blah blah...
});
```